# Help and Improvement queue favouring favorite tags?

Tags: discussion, help-improvement

I got the impression that the questions in the Help and Improvement that I get to review are disproportionally showing ones that have one of my Favorite tags. At least if there is a choice and the queue is not close to being cleared.

Is this so? If not is there some other selection going on? It certainly doesn't seem to be first in, first out.

Comment: I have no idea if this is intentional, but it does make sense.  What better questions for you to review than the ones in the tags that you say you are an expert in?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't necessarily have to be an expert, to be interested. But I am not complaining. However, if it is **not** intentional and I do actually get a disproportional amount of reviews related to the tags I am interesting in, there might be some other cause worth investigating.